# How to disable eval function without going to php.ini file?

Tags: php, function, eval

Is there a way to disable **eval** function without doing so from php.ini file.
I have tried **ini_set** function but even that doesn't work.

Basically I want my framework users to decide whether this function should be enabled or not through a config file. If they say no, i should be able to disable it using code as i can't go to server of each users where my framework is installed and disabling it using php.ini file.

As i said without goint to php.ini file, so ini directive **disable_functions** should not be posted in answers.

Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It won't work, because eval() is not a function - it's a language construct. You can disable it with [suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/), a protection system for PHP. That's the only way I know of.

From PHP.net:

> ```
> Note: Because this is a language construct and not a function,
> it cannot be called using variable functions
> ```

Answer (score 1):

if this is *mod_php* (not CGI) with apache, .htaccess will work.  other than that... bad luck.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/mk-j/PHP_diseval_extension allows you to disable eval in php7 as well as php5.  Suhosin is only stable in php5.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could call `override_function` with a new function which does nothing. (req APD)

Comment: It's not a function, it's a language construct.